# Bottom gravity is not working on bitmap in layerlist on some phones

Tags: android, layer-list

I am working on android app where I am using concept of layerlist. I have set one bitmap in center of the screen, and one at the bottom of the screen. On Android 4.2, bitmap is set at the bottom correctly but On Android 6.0.1 bottom bitmap is not showing when I add bottom margin of item.

If I set the margin then it adds margin in Android 4.2 also where bitmaps is visible after certain margin from the bottom but correct on Android 6.0.1.

Can anyone guess what could be the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item>
        <bitmap

            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/powered" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Show your current output

Comment: can you please share the solution

Comment: If you still finding for a solution. Chrck this out! https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534889/6892411