# setting bitmap gravity as bottom goes off the screen layer-list in Oreo

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have my splash view as xml file like below. this code works perfectly fine using target version as api 19 (kitkat)  but once I change using target as Oreo,half of the splash_text at the bottom goes off the screen. why is that happening and how can I fix it? targeting kitkat , splash text is perfectly right at the buttom. I tried to add  layout_margin on bitmap but it didnt help me either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/background_material_light"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap 
        android:src="@drawable/splash_text"
        android:tileMode="disabled" 
        android:gravity="bottom"        
        />    
  </item>  
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you set the gravity of the bitmap. It's just like the behavior of that attribute for bitmap element pushes it outside the screen. Therefore, by adding some margin on the item element to pushes it inside the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <item android:top="25dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="75dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below theme to your app it will work just fine.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`